# Get listview clicks from sidenavigation

Tags: android, eclipse

I have implemented the Sliding Menu in my App. Source: https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation

It works like it should but when I click on any item in my menu, the click wont work some reason. I added onClick listener and all that.

Code snippet:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),( R.string.title1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
    switch (itemId) {
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),( R.string.title1),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DiffAdapter.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item3:
        invokeActivity(getString(R.string.title3), R.drawable.ic_action_storage);
        break;

    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item4:
        invokeActivity(getString(R.string.title4), R.drawable.ic_action_settings);
        break;

    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item5:
        invokeActivity(getString(R.string.title5), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        break;

    default:
        return;
    }
    finish();
}
```

Any help would be nice. It just wont do anything when I click on a item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to implement some strings, which caused bugs. Got this solved by adding:

```
icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
        sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.ribbon_menu);
        sideNavigationView.setMenuClickCallback(this);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_TITLE)) {
            String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
            int resId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, 0);
            setTitle(title);
            icon.setImageResource(resId);
        }
```

to my code: onCreate ()